# VS2008 How to deploy a WebSite Application Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

So I have created a Web Site Application project in VS2008 and is fine on my local machine. Just wondering how to I deploy this to a dev server i.e via FTP i.e. do I need just copy over all files i.e.

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution
Visual Basic Project File
Visual Studio Project User options File
and the rest of my customer folder and files & web.config ?

And then when I have those moved and i.e I want to change the config file on the dev server, can I just change the web.config directly on that server or do I need to then open it visual studio on that server and recompile again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Publish Web Site options under Build Menu.

This option can deploy directly on the remote site whit FTP or can publish the file needed on a foolder on your local computer, so you only have to upload on the remote site.

After you deploy the web site if you have only to change the web.config you can use Notepd for it and don't need to recompile nothing... only if you change CodeBehind you have to recompile and upload only the DLL.

This [link](http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/deploying-your-site-using-visual-studio-cs) can Help you understan all the process